# simpson integration on python

Tags: python-3.x, numerical-methods

I am trying to integrate numerically using simpson integration rule for f(x) = 2x from 0 to 1, but keep getting a large error. The desired output is 1 but, the output from python is 1.334. Can someone help me find a solution to this problem?
thank you.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return 2*x

def simpson(f,a,b,n):
    x = np.linspace(a,b,n)
    dx = (b-a)/n
    for i in np.arange(1,n):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            y = 4*f(x)
        elif i % 2 == 0:
            y = 2*f(x)
    return (f(a)+sum(y)+f(x)[-1])*dx/3

a = 0
b = 1
n = 1000
ans = simpson(f,a,b,n)
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is everything wrong. `x` is an array, everytime you call `f(x)`, you are evaluating the function over the whole array. As `n` is even and `n-1` odd, the `y` in the last loop is `4*f(x)` and from its sum something is computed

Then `n` is the number of segments. The number of points is `n+1`.  A correct implementation is

```
def simpson(f,a,b,n):
    x = np.linspace(a,b,n+1)
    y = f(x)
    dx = x[1]-x[0]
    return (y[0]+4*sum(y[1::2])+2*sum(y[2:-1:2])+y[-1])*dx/3

simpson(lambda x:2*x, 0, 1, 1000)
```

which then correctly returns `1.000`. You might want to add a test if `n` is even, and increase it by one if that is not the case.

---

If you really want to keep the loop, you need to actually accumulate the sum inside the loop.

```
def simpson(f,a,b,n):
    dx = (b-a)/n;
    res = 0; 
    for i in range(1,n): res += f(a+i*dx)*(2 if i%2==0 else 4); 
    return (f(a)+f(b) + res)*dx/3;

simpson(lambda x:2*x, 0, 1, 1000)
```

But loops are generally slower than vectorized operations, so if you use numpy, use vectorized operations. Or just use directly `scipy.integrate.simps`.

Comment: Because you do not do anything in the loop but repeatedly computing all function values and assigning a multiple of the whole array to `y`. I'll add a loop variant.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. i know there are some toolbox for this operation but i want to learn the algorithm.